# Dependence of the Littlewood-Paley constant on the partition

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

One simple version of the Littlewood-Paley theorem is an estimate
$$A_p\|f\|_{L^p}\leq \|Sf\|_{L^p}\leq B_p\|f\|_{L^p}$$
where $$Sf=\left(\sum_{k}\left(\sum_{\lambda^k<|n|\leq \lambda^{k+1}}\hat f(n)e(nt)\right)^2\right)^{1/2}$$.

Here $\lambda>1$ is some parameter. I am interested in how the constants $A_p$ and $B_p$ change with $
\lambda$. In particular, what happens when $\lambda\to \infty$?

Comment: It is probably obvious, but I want to double check: notation-wise: are you working on the torus, with $n\in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and $t\in \mathbb{T}^d$?

Comment: Sure, even with $d=1$.

Comment: Silly question: how do you incorporate the 0 frequency mode in your summation?

Comment: I suppose so, even though it doesn't appear to be the case as written. I don't really see it as too big a deal.